# Weak* convergence of increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I have a sequence $(f_n)_n : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ of strictly increasing functions.

$f_n$s are, in general, not left or right continuous. If they were right continuous, from what I know, we have results that show that there exists a function $f$ such that $f_n \to f$ in the weak* topology.

Are there any results that suggest that this sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ in some sense? Would it help if I knew that $f_n$s are usc?

Comment: The notion of weak-* convergence involves topological vector space. Which space are you considering here?

Comment: The space is a space of weakly increasing functions that map $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: [Helly's selection theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397931/hellys-selection-theorem)?

Comment: Correct of I am wrong, but except that identifying such functions with Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures on $[0,1]$ and then embedding them into the dual space of $C([0,1])$ (which essentially induces the vague topology on them), I see no clear way of equipping a topological vector space structure (and hence the weak-* topology) on the family of weakly increasing functions $[0,1]\to[0,1]$...