# Trouble with uniform convergence in Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f:[a,b]\to H$ for an arbitrary real-valued Hilbert space $H$ be continuous on the real interval $[a,b]$. We are given that $B=\{b_k:k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$. I am trying to show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle f(t),b_k\rangle^2$$ converges uniformly to $\|f(t)\|^2$ on the interval.

I'm easily able to show pointwise convergence just using the fact that there is a sequence of scalars $(\alpha_k)_t$ such that for any $t$ in the interval
$$f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_kb_k.$$
I know I need to bring in the continuity of $f$ to gain uniform convergence but I'm not sure how to do that in my present argument. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote 
$$
 f_n(t) := \sum_{k=1}^n  \langle f(t), b_k \rangle^2.
$$
Then, the $f_n$ are continuous, increasing and converge pointwise to the continuous function $g(t) := \lVert f(t) \rVert^2$. The fact that the $f_n$ are increasing implies uniform convergence.

See for example [Sequence of monotone functions converging to a continuous limit, is the convergence uniform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834126/sequence-of-monotone-functions-converging-to-a-continuous-limit-is-the-converge).

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't realise that there was such a result. It certainly wasn't mentioned in my undergrad analysis courses, which is strange considering how useful it seems.

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, for some reason it is not well known (as it was for me, after I needed it to prove a $C^*$-algebraic result !).