# Sufficient condition under which a pointwise convergent becomes uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $K$ be any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then what are the
>   sufficient conditions so that any pointwise convergent sequence of functions on $K$ converges uniformly.

The conditions can be given as in [Dini's Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) Can we have other conditions (Weaker) apart from Dini's theorem so that this becomes true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another standard theorem is the following:

Let $f_k \colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions, such that $f_k$ is  non-increasing (resp. non-decreasing) for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
If $(f_k)$ converges pointwise to a **continuous** function $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is non-increasing (resp. non-decreasing) and the convergence is uniform.

Note that in this theorem the monotonicity is in the $x\in [a,b]$ variable, whereas in Dini's theorem is on the index $k$.

Comment: Can you give some reference for this theorem?

Comment: You can find the proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834126/sequence-of-monotone-functions-converging-to-a-continuous-limit-is-the-converge