# Why is this convergence uniform?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, uniform-convergence

**Edit:** The probabilistic context below is probably not important. The question is simply why $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $\pi^{-1}(x(1-x))^{-1/2}$ on compact subsets of $(0,1)$, where $f_n$ is the step function equal to $n{2k \choose k}{2\left(n-k\right) \choose n-k}2^{-2n}$ on $[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]$. Pointwise convergence follows from Stirling's Approximation.

**Originial formulation, including the context:**

I am reading the proof of Theorem 4.9.5 in *Probability: Theory and Examples* by Durett, available online [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) (page 265 of the book / page 273 of the PDF file).

Let $X_1,X_2,\dotsc$ be i.i.d. with $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$.
Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ (a simple random walk).
Let $L_{n}=\sup\{m\leq 2n\mid S_m=0\}$ (the last visit to $0$ among the first $2n$ steps).

**What I do understand:**

1. $nP(L_{2n}=2k)=n{2k \choose k}{2\left(n-k\right) \choose n-k}2^{-2n}\to\pi^{-1}(x(1-x))^{-1/2}$ as $n\to\infty$ and $k/n\to x$.
2. **Defintion:** $f_n$ is a step function equal to $nP(L_{2n}=2k)$ on $[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]$.

**What I do not understand:**

A bit later in the proof, it is claimed that $f_n$ converges uniformly on compact sets (**Edit:** I mean on compact subsets of $(0,1)$).

> Why is the convergence uniform on these compact sets?

Comment: What should be true for a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ to converge uniformly on a compact? Perhaps we could try to verify the hypotheses of an analysis theorem.

Comment: @A.P. I hope so. We have $nP\left(L_{2n}=2k\right)=n{2k \choose k}{2\left(n-k\right) \choose n-k}2^{-2n}$, and the pointwise limit is continuous (on $(0,1)$, where I care about convergence on compacts). Maybe it's possible to use https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2407312 in some way, but probably not directly.