# Uniform continuity on different intervals

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

We know that $f_n:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of nondecreasing functions  on interval $(0,1)$ and that $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Let $A\subset (0,1)$ be a dense subset of $(0,1)$, which fulfills the condition
$$ \forall_{x\in A}  \ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x).$$
With this assumptions I have to

a) show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on every $[a,b]\subset(0,1)$,

b) answer if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $(0,1)$.

My attempts:

a) We have to show that
$$ \forall_{\epsilon>0} \ \exists_{n_0=n_0(\epsilon)} \forall_{x\in [a,b]}\forall_{n>n_0} \ \ |f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon.$$
For $f_n(x)$, $x\in A$, where $A$ is a dense subset of $(0,1)$ we can observe pointwise convergence, so let's take $[a,b]$ in such a way to make it a dense subset of $(0,1)$. Then for every $\epsilon$ we will be able to choose such $n_0=n_0(\epsilon)$ that $\forall_{x\in [a,b]}\forall_{n>n_0} \ \ |f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ (from the point convergence).

b) $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f$ on $(0,1)$ because on this interval doesn't converge even pointwise.

Are my solutions sensible? If not, I politely ask for help. Thanks in advance and have a good day.

Comment: Dense sets may not contain intervals and why subset of a dense set should be dense ?

Comment: Yes, you are right - the subset of dense set doesn't have to be dense. I will try to modify my solution but it may be still wrong.

Comment: @Dmitry how from only the fact that functions are nondecreasing can we conclude that we have pointwise convergence?

Comment: @Novice, now it's a complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)

- First, we show pointwise convergence. For any $x$ we build increasing $x_k \to x$ and decreasing $x'_k \to x$, belonging to $A$. For any $n$, we have
  $$f_n(x_k) \le f_n(x) \le f_n(x'_k)$$
  Since $f_n$ converges on $A$,
  $$\forall k\ \forall \epsilon\ \exists n_{k,\epsilon}:\ \forall n > n_{k,\epsilon} \ \ |f_n(x_k) - f(x_k)| < \frac \epsilon 2 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
  On the other hand, since $f$ is continuous:
  $$\forall \epsilon\ \exists k_{\epsilon}:\ \forall k \ge k_{\epsilon} \ \ |f(x_k) - f(x)| < \frac \epsilon 2 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
  (The same for $x'_k$). Therefore, $\forall n > n_{k_\epsilon,\epsilon}$
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  \text{(by \eqref{eq1} for $k \gets k_\epsilon$)} \quad\quad
  & f(x_{k_\epsilon}) &- \frac \epsilon 2 &\le f_n(x) &\le f(x'_{k_\epsilon}) &+ \frac \epsilon 2 \Rightarrow \\
  \text{(by \eqref{eq2} for $k \gets k_\epsilon$)} \quad\quad
  & f(x) &- \epsilon &\le f_n(x) &\le f(x) &+ \epsilon
  \end{alignat}
  I.e., we have a pointwise convergence at point $x$.
- Uniform convergence on $[a,b]$ is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/834179/743044).

b) It's false: consider
$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
-\frac 1x, & x < \frac 1n \\
0, & x \ge \frac 1n
\end{cases}$.
For each $x$, we have $f_n(x) \to f(x) = 0$. But convergence is not uniform: for any $n$ and $\epsilon$ there exists $x = \min(\frac 1 {2n}, \frac 1 {2 \epsilon})$: $f_n(x) \le -2 \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask from which property have we the last inequality in b)? If I am guessing correctly it is something like $f_n(x)\leq f(x)$.

Comment: Well, I just substituted $x$ into $f_n(x)$... I guess I’ve used that $f_n$ is monotone

Comment: @Dmitry  If $k\gt k_{\epsilon}$ then does
$|f_n(x_k)-f (x_k)|\lt \epsilon/2  $ hold for $ n\gt n_{k_{\epsilon},\epsilon}?$  because I think you are using the above (unclaimed) fact to prove the second last inequality in proving pointwise convergence at point $x$. If I am wrong , then please justify how do you get the inequality I mentioned.

Comment: @Dmitry  According to me, your inequality is still valid by taking $n\gt 
 n_{k_{\epsilon},\epsilon}$ and writing $f_n(x) \ge f_n(x_{k_{\epsilon}}) \ge f(x_{k_{\epsilon}})-\frac{\epsilon}2 \ge f(x)-\epsilon$. Is this wrong ?

Comment: @user710290, thanks! I've fixed it. it suffices to just consider $k_\epsilon$ itself.

Comment: @Dmitry  Thanks for the clarification. +1 from me!