Question on the proof of Dini's theorem
I'm trying to prove Dini's Theorem, particularly for closed intervals $[a,b]$, and the idea is basically the same as in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/834179.
Using the fact that $f$ is continuous on the compact interval $[a,b]$, we know it's uniformly continuous. For $|x - y| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. With this, we can induce a partition with norm $\delta$, and for $x, y \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. By the pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $f$, we can make a partition of $[a,b]$, and we find an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ and for all $x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$, we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
Using these facts, we can reach the same conclusion. My problem is that for uniform convergence, we need to find $M(\epsilon)$ such that for every $x \in [a,b]$ and every $n \geq M(\epsilon)$, we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. However, the $N$ from the pointwise convergence of $f_n$ is chosen, i.e., $M = N(\epsilon, x)$, and we are not really removing the dependence on the point. So, my question is: what $N$ can I choose to remove the point dependence?

Use $N$ corresponding to the points $x_i$ and take the maximum of those.
